# about linux NPM install pm2 and error like this

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu

I install pm2 and error like this . Can anyone help?

```
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /pm2/chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.14
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/package.json'
npm WARN root No description
npm WARN root No repository field.
npm WARN root No README data
npm WARN root No license field.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`fsevents` package.json](https://github.com/strongloop/fsevents/blob/master/package.json#L10-L12) specifically only supports the `darwin` OS architecture:

```
  "os": [
    "darwin"
  ]
```

However, as it is an optional dependency, you can safely ignore this error.

To suppress it entirely, you can tell npm to ignore any optional dependencies when installing:

```
npm install --no-optional
```

Comment: oh,got.  But i installed pm2  and cannot  use command 'pm2'.   so   what's the trouble